# Connecting PC to the internet over ethernet

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

## I have the following setup:

Laptop(Ubuntu 18.04) is connected to the internet over Wi-Fi.

PC(Ubuntu 18.04) is connected to the laptop using ethernet cable.

When the laptop is running VPN, the PC doesn't connect to the internet.

How can i establish connection with VPN running?
I don't want the PC to share the VPN connection.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.50.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 proton0
0.0.0.0         192.168.225.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
10.50.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 proton0
128.0.0.0       10.50.0.1       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 proton0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
172.16.174.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
172.83.43.131   192.168.225.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.220.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

Comment: Post the output of `route`

Comment: is proton0 the vpn?

Comment: @rtaft that's right

Answer (score 0):

For my VPN, I try to keep non essential traffic off of the VPN as it's slow.  The basic premise is to remove the default route to the VPN, and add in specific routes that you use for the VPN.  Mine has 'default' instead of 0.0.0.0 but I'll assume it's the same.  My delete looks like this:

```
route delete -net default gw 0.0.0.0 dev vpn0
```

So yours might be something like:

```
route delete -net 0.0.0.0 gw 128.0.0.0 dev proton0
```

This should route all traffic back through the ethernet, but it may break the VPN.  You have other proton0 entries so it may work fine.  From there I add specific networks that I need.  For instance 172.16.0.0 is a common one, as is 10.0.0.0:

```
route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.240.0.0 dev vpn0
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev vpn0
```

You would need to use the routes that you need for the VPN, and set the device to proton0.  If things break completely, you can turn off and on the network and vpn and it should reset the settings.

If you manage to get this working, you can make this permanent by adding the file `/etc/network/if-up.d/proton0` and inside you do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "proton0" ]; then
   route delete -net 0.0.0.0 gw 128.0.0.0 dev proton0
   route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev proton0
   route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.240.0.0 dev proton0
fi
```

Only replace the route commands with what you used to get it working.  You may have to do more than this to get the 2nd computer routing properly as this is setup is for keeping the internet traffic off the VPN.  I'm not 100% sure it will fix the second computer.